# CSS/HTML layout idea issue

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm looking at making something like in the image below. I don't know how I would go about this, so if someone could link me to a tutorial or quickly write an example up, it would help a lot.

[image]

Comment: Simple  - use table.

Comment: dam, reason I didn't know is because I skipped learning tables as I thought I'd never need it!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class='view-data'>

  <div class='view-data-header'><h1>Title here</h1></div>

  <div class='view-data-content'>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><img src='' alt='' /></th>
          <th>Col Title 1</th>
          <th>Col Title 2</th>
          <th>Col Title 3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><img src='' alt='' /></td>
          <td>Content 1</td>
          <td>Content 2</td>
          <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><img src='' alt='' /></td>
          <td>Content 1</td>
          <td>Content 2</td>
          <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><img src='' alt='' /></td>
          <td>Content 1</td>
          <td>Content 2</td>
          <td>Content 3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div> <!-- end of .view-data-content -->

  <div class='view-data-footer'>
    <a href='link.html'>Link title</a>
  </div>

</div> <!-- end of .view-data -->
```